# Google Charts API Z-index

Tags: z-index, positioning, google-visualization

Given:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=0,0,21|1,0,320&chxt=x,y&chs=600x500&cht=s&chco=c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0&chd=t:5,5,5,5,10,5,5,5,5,10,19,29,14,14,24,62,24,5,19,10,10,24,10,14,10,29,14,24,100,14,10,10,19,24,52,14,24,43,29,14,24,24,10,19,29,24,19,29,10,38,5,5,5,24,10,10,24,52,14,14,14,10,10,5,19,10,5,14,14,10,14,19,14,19,10,5,5,10,10,10,10,24,10,5,5,5,5,10,14,24,5,5,10,5,14,14,5,5,14,5,29,10,14,5,14,10,62,10,10,19,5,5|3,2,4,4,4,10,4,10,5,100,24,56,52,69,52,75,42,29,41,35,25,35,53,45,52,75,51,75,100,53,29,75,32,83,100,62,83,100,38,29,56,62,42,62,29,39,53,32,32,48,43,20,28,37,41,27,34,43,41,17,37,17,42,22,59,24,23,47,23,43,19,50,50,47,44,43,42,42,40,40,38,37,35,35,35,35,34,34,34,33,29,26,23,22,24,35,16,20,29,25,25,21,11,16,21,23,16,20,15,22,16,23

Which produces:

[image]

I'm having trouble forcing the black dots to the top, does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: I would have never even looked at Google Charts had I not seen your question... but I'm glad that I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move black dots to the end:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=0,0,21|1,0,320&chxt=x,y&chs=600x500&cht=s&chco=c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|c0c0c0|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000|000000&chd=t:5,5,5,5,10,5,5,5,5,10,19,29,14,14,24,62,24,5,19,10,10,24,10,14,10,29,14,24,100,14,10,10,19,24,52,14,24,43,29,14,24,24,10,19,29,24,19,10,5,19,10,5,14,14,10,14,19,14,19,10,5,5,10,10,10,10,24,10,5,5,5,5,10,14,24,5,5,10,5,14,14,5,5,14,5,29,10,14,5,14,10,62,10,10,19,5,5,29,10,38,5,5,5,24,10,10,24,52,14,14,14,10|3,2,4,4,4,10,4,10,5,100,24,56,52,69,52,75,42,29,41,35,25,35,53,45,52,75,51,75,100,53,29,75,32,83,100,62,83,100,38,29,56,62,42,62,29,39,53,42,22,59,24,23,47,23,43,19,50,50,47,44,43,42,42,40,40,38,37,35,35,35,35,34,34,34,33,29,26,23,22,24,35,16,20,29,25,25,21,11,16,21,23,16,20,15,22,16,23,32,32,48,43,20,28,37,41,27,34,43,41,17,37,17

[image]

**EDIT:**  BTW: There is no *z-index* for `chd` based on goolge's documentation

Comment: there is no z-index for `chd`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging using the [Chart Wizard](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_wizard.html)? It seems your black data points are located in the middle of your supplied data. Move them to the start/finish and see if that helps.